# Google-maps for Business Authentication Issue with Python-Requests

Tags: python, google-maps, python-requests

I am having issues incorporating my new Business credentials into the Python-Requests module I had previously been using with the free user API key to create requests.

I have been following the authentication directions given by Google - (1) parsing the base URL into its path and query parts (2) decoding the private key to binary (3) creating a signature using this private key and the URL-encoded string using HMAC SHA1 (4) encoding the binary signature using base64

My code is as follows -

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import urlparse
import hashlib
import base64
import hmac
from pprint import pprint

url_raw = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json&client=REMOVED'
Private_Key = 'REMOVED'

with open('./Origins.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    origincoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]

with open('./Destinations.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    destinationcoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]

results=[] 

url = urlparse.urlparse('url_raw')

url_to_sign = url.path + '?' + url.query

decodedKey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(Private_Key)

signature = hmac.new(decodedKey, url_to_sign, hashlib.sha1)

encodedSignature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest())

originalUrl = url.scheme + "://" + url.netloc + url.path + '?' + url.query

Full_URL = originalUrl + "&signature=" + encodedSignature

for i in range(0,(len(origincoords))):
    params ={'origin': origincoords[i],
          'destination': destinationcoords[i],
          'encodedSignature': encodedSignature}

    directions = requests.get(Full_URL, params=params).json()
    results.append(directions)
```

At this point I parse the results of the relevant information for my research. Thanks to @fredtantini for the help here previously.

The error message I am currently getting relates to a requests.exception, stating that I am not using a valid schema. However, in my code I have included the url.scheme in the originalUrl variable, which makes up part of the Full_URL which is used in the requests generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the value of `url_raw`. You are parsing the **string** with the contents `'url_raw'`:

```
url = urlparse.urlparse('url_raw')
```

Remove the quotes around `url_raw`, you want to parse the value associated with the variable, not a string that just happens to contain text that is equal to the variable name.

Demo:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url_raw = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json&client=REMOVED'
>>> urlparse.urlparse('url_raw')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='url_raw', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.urlparse(url_raw)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='maps.googleapis.com', path='/maps/api/directions/json&client=REMOVED', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Note how in the first case `scheme` is an empty string, while when parsing the actual URL the scheme is set to `'https'` instead.

Next, you to produce the signature for the query string *as a whole*, not just the path plus client id.

You can best do that by creating a *prepared* request, *after* attaching the query parameters:

```
session = requests.Session()

for origin, destination in zip(origincoords, destinationcoords):
    params ={'origin': origin, 'destination': destination}
    request = requests.Request('GET', Full_URL, params=params).prepare()
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(request.url)
    signature = hmac.new(decodedKey, '{}?{}'.format(parsed_url.path, parsed_url.query),
                         hashlib.sha1).digest()
    request.prepare_url(request.url, {'signature': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature)})
    response = session.send(request)
    directions = response.json()

    results.append(directions)
```

This uses a [`PreparedRequest` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) to produce the URL for us, so we can parse that again for ease of signing. The [`PreparedRequest.prepare_url()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_url) then lets us add the signature to the URL of that object, after which we can easily send it with a session object.

Comment: Many thanks @Martijn. I see that now. Unfortunately I am now getting a 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'

Comment: @LearningSlowly: so what *was* returned then? Use `response = requests.get(Full_URL, params=params)`, then look at `response.headers` and `response.content` to see what Google returned to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe I am getting anything back from google. As the error was in the line - 
    directions = requests.get(Full_URL, params=params).json()
Which is where the requests are actually sent

Comment: @LearningSlowly: Looking at the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#digital_signatures) it is clear you need to sign the *final parameter list*, not just the client id.

Comment: Exactly, I need to find the requests argument which builds, but does not send the requests. Thank you

Comment: @LearningSlowly: that's exactly what the `request.Request` object does; preparing it builds the URL for us, and we can tell it to update the URL with the signature too.

Comment: Fantastic @Martijn. you are very patient. incredibly helpful

Comment: I left out the decode of the private key because that belongs outside the loop. Do that *once*, at the top.

Comment: Another lesson! Thank you

Comment: I don't quite follow the advantage of preparing a request and then sending. Is this for a speed benefit?

Comment: @mptevsion I state in my answer why; in order to get the encoded URL for signing.